# Selenium C#: Get text from multiple divs of same name

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am trying to get text from all the threads in a chat, and they are of same name.I Intend to put them all in a txt doc.
e.g

```
<div data-tid="message" dir="auto"><div>Text1</div></div>
.....
<div data-tid="message" dir="auto"><div>Text2</div></div>
```

I am trying to use a loop to get text from all divs, but cannot get attribute within loop.

```
IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> chatRow = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@data-tid='message']/div"));
for (int i = 0; i < chatRow.Count; i++)
{
    GetAttribute("innerHTML");
}
```

Is there a way a do it without a loop? or how to get attributes from within the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are using `FindElement` instead of `FindElements`

Replace

```
IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> chatRow = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@data-tid='message']/div"));
```

With

```
IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> chatRow = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@data-tid='message']/div"));
for (int i = 0; i < chatRow.Count; i++)
{
    chatRow.ElementAt(i).GetAttribute("innerHTML");
}
```